# Nagios - Raise notification for second time occurrence of an error in log file

Tags: notifications, nagios, logfile

I have a log file "sample.log"  on Windows , The Log file is rotated every 4 Hours.  Each line in the log file has timestamp.  There is error Message in the log file "Connection with Server ABC Failed"  I have to ignore this error Message on its first occurrence and to ignore the notification alert.  But Objective is to raise a notification alert when the same Error Message "Connection with Server ABC Failed" in the "sample.log" file occurs "second time or more". How this can be achieved , Please assist ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a large learning curve with this plugin, but I'd use the **check_logfiles** plugin for this.
https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/

I haven't had to use this particular feature yet, but from the documentation it seems you can achieve your goals setting `criticalthreshold` to `2`.

Of course you'll also need to specify your `criticalpattern` regex and I'd recommend setting an `okpattern` if possible.

In my service definition I also had to be sure to include:

```
is_volatile                     1
```

Installation instructions are included in the link above.